# Deployment error in CXF 3.0.3 in generated top down Java service from WSDL

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, tomcat7, cxf

I would very much appreciate your help with this issue.

Configuration is Eclipse Juno, CXF 3.0.3 runtime and Tomcat v7. 
I have used CXF to create Web service top down from ready WSDL approach.
But when deploying service on Tomcat I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]
```

Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml] 
cannot be opened because it does not exist

I simple cannot find a solution to this error and I'm stuck for long time.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in WebContent/WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml, remove import

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/ cxf/ cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
```

Comment: I have marked useful answer but still not checked it on my environment.

Comment: Konstantin has given the document backing the solution.

Comment: Thank you, I have to come back to this and test it.

Answer (score 9):

According to [documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/embedding-cxf-inside-spring.html) you don't need to import this file anymore in CXF 3:

> Starting in CXF 2.4.0, the extensions are loaded internally by CXF automatically and you do not need to import all the cxf-extension-*.xml file. You only need to import classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your solution provided? In the cxf-beans.xml generated automatically by CXF, there is imported `<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />`.  Also web.xml has been updated automatically with servlet configurations. Still I can't figure up what is wrong.

Comment: Check the version of CXF generator you use - it may be too old and generates code for pre-2.4.x version of CXF runtime

Comment: CXF is 3.0.3. It has been configured at Eclipse->Preferences->Web Services.

Comment: Meanwhile I have added the cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.0.3.jar to the project WEB-INF/lib and getting **new error**:   `class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-all.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`. Question is what else cxf*.jars needs to be still added, and is this correct? I mean that is a long list of CXF jars.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue with updating cxf 2.2.6 to 3.1.0. I just removed import cxf-extension-soap.xml and it worked.

Comment: I have to check this your suggestion in my environment.